# Chrome doesn't understand encoded Content-Disposition filename created by .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, content-disposition

I get an interesting problem when the filename is long and contains a non-ASCII character. Here is what happens:

For this example, I have chosen the filename *VeryVeryT=250°CSuperVeryFreakingVeryWowSoVeryCrazyLongFilenameWithOnlyASingleCrazyWeirdNonAsciiCharacterWhatCouldGoWrong.txt* which has a single non-ASCII character.

1. If I download this file through my ASP.NET application, the Content-Disposition header in the response is:

   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?utf-8?B?VmVyeVZlcnlUPTI1MMKwQ1N1cGVyVmVyeUZyZWFraW5nVmVyeVdvd1Nv?=%0d%0a =?utf-8?B?VmVyeUNyYXp5X1NpbmdsZUNyYXp5V2VpcmROb25Bc2NpaUNoYXJhY3Rl?=%0d%0a =?utf-8?B?cldoYXRDb3VsZEdvV3Jvbmcuemlw?="
2. If I email myself the same file in GMail and download it, the header in that case looks like this:

   content-disposition:attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?VmVyeVZlcnlUPSAyNTDCsENTdXBlclZlcnlGcmVha2k=?= =?UTF-8?B?bmdWZXJ5V293U29WZXJ5Q3JhenlMb25nRmlsZW5hbQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?ZVdpdGhPbmx5QVNpbmdsZUNyYXp5V2VpcmROb25Bcw==?= =?UTF-8?B?Y2lpQ2hhcmFjdGVyV2hhdENvdWxkR29Xcm9uZy50eHQ=?="

In the first case, Chrome doesn't understand the header and downloads an extensionless file with the generic name "*Download*". In the second case, it downloads the file with the correct name.

Firefox, on the other hand, handles the first case better but there still seems to be a problem with what .NET has constructed. It downloads a file with the name *VeryVeryT=250°CSuperVeryFreakingVeryWowSo%0d%0a VeryCrazy_SingleCrazyWeirdNonAsciiCharacte%0d%0a rWhatCouldGoWrong.txt*.

My application is using the `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition`class. Here is the code that I have written:

```
internal static FileStreamResult GetFileStreamResult(Stream fileStream, string fileDownloadName)
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(
            fileStream: fileStream,
            contentType: MIConstants.DefaultEmbeddedFileContentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName
        };
    }
```

Is this really a bug with .NET or am I missing something?

Comment: The %0d%0a is a new line (\r\n) in URL encoded format which does not look right at all mixed in with that rfc1522 encoding, the format should be cr-lf-space for a multi line header.

Comment: This .NET 4.0 bug sounds very similar https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2402064/an-email-message-attachment-name-that-contains-non-ascii-characters-and-is-longer-than-41-utf-8-encoded-bytes-is-encoded-two-times-before-transmission-in-an-application-that-is-compiled-for-the-.net-framework-4 I am targeting .NET 4.5.2 though...

Comment: Tf this Content-Disposition field value appears as *HTTP* header field, it's broken. Consult RFC 6266 for the correct syntax.